# What does a name represent for a primitive variable such as uint256 ? How does EVM know a variable with a name is linked to a value on stack?

Tags: solidity, evm

A primitive variable such as:

```
uint256 var;
```

or

```
uint256 var = 0xffff;
```

stores a value. And this value is on the stack of EVM.

1. What exactly is the name 'var' ?
2. How EVM knows 'var' points to 0xffff ?
3. How is var linked to its value ? Is var an identifier that points to location on stack ? Kinda pointer to stack ?
4. What does a declared but uninitialized var represent ? Is it some kind of pointer with no reference to a stack slot ?